# Is there a way to plot 3 (or more) charts on the same line

Tags: python, seaborn

I have the dataframe `df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])`. I know I can use `sns.distplot(df.col1)` to plot a histogram for each column. Can I plot separate histograms for all 3 columns on the same line?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you should use matplotlib here:

```
fig = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots(nrows=1, 
                           ncols=3)
fig.plot(df['col1'])
fig.plot(df['col2'])
fig.plot(df['col3'])
plt.show()
```

I think this will work well well. For external reference you can go to https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-a-subplots-in-matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 2)
sns.distplot(df.col1, ax=ax1)
sns.distplot(df.col2, ax=ax2)
```

Edited:
To adjust the size of the subplots, use `plt.subplots`[documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html)

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3, gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [3, 1, 1]})
sns.distplot(df.col1, ax=axs[0])
sns.distplot(df.col2, ax=axs[1])
```

The subplots will have 3:1:1 width ratios.

Comment: Thanks. How do you adjust the size of the subplots?